# How to end setinterval?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have problem is interval. When i declare function she have setinterval and if i clearinterval she continues to be executed. Code:

```
if (score == 1) {
    leftBlinkTimer(0)
 } else if (score == 0) {
    leftBlinkTimer(1)
 }

function leftBlinkTimer (state) {
    let leftBlin = 0;
    var timer;
    if (state == 0) {
        timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (leftBlin == 0) {
                const newData = {
                    stateLeftBlinker: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'
                }
                vm.changeMicro(newData)
                leftBlin = 1;
            } else if (leftBlin == 1) {
                const newData = {
                    stateLeftBlinker: '#47EC5B'
                }
                vm.changeMicro(newData)
                leftBlin = 0;
            }
        },600)
    } else if (state == 1 || state == '1') {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
```

I try check state in timer and clear, and it's not working. Both 0 and 1 come to state.Thanks for help :)
I'm waiting for the time to end

Comment: Your `timer` variable needs to be declared outside the function so that its value can be preserved between calls to `leftBlinkTimer()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to the scoping of the `timer` variable inside the `leftBlinkTimer` function. The `timer` variable is declared inside the function's scope, so when you call `clearInterval(timer)`, it won't refer to the same `timer` that was created in the previous call to `leftBlinkTimer`.

declaring it outside would help